# writing the input arguments for a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using this function on matlab

```
[ProbData,HazData] = cdsbootstrap(ZeroData,MarketData,Settle,[],[],[],[],[],[],0.25)
```

and it is giving me an error because it dose not understand the `[ ]`.

I want to keep the default inputs from 4-->9 and change the ninth input to 0.25. What should I put instead of the `[ ]`?

Comment: What are "the default inputs from 4-->9"? A little bit more context would be fine.

Comment: According to the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/cdsbootstrap.html) this function only takes 3 arguments, plus name value pairs. Which Name/Value pair are you trying to change to 0.25? The possible ones are also listed on that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `cdsbootstrap` uses matlab's very common Name/Value pair syntax. Read the first few lines [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/cdsbootstrap.html#namevaluepairarguments):

> Specify optional comma-separated pairs of Name,Value arguments. Name
>   is the argument name and Value is the corresponding value. Name must
>   appear inside single quotes (' '). You can specify several name and
>   value pair arguments in any order as Name1,Value1,...,NameN,ValueN.

So if you wanted ALL default values, you would use the call:

```
[ProbData,HazData] = cdsbootstrap(ZeroData,MarketData,Settle);
```

If you wanted to change one of these possiblities you would simply include the name and value, all names omitted are set to defaults. Based on your value of 0.25 I'm going to assume you are trying to set the RecoveryRate since 0.25 is close to the default.

```
[ProbData,HazData] = cdsbootstrap(ZeroData,MarketData,Settle,'RecoveryRate',0.25);
```

Ref:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/cdsbootstrap.html

Comment: ('RecoveryRate',0.25) worked  ,i really appreciate it thank you